# Add Relationship to Entity in a Content Datasource View?

Tags: views, search, 9

Good afternoon,

I have configured a (Search API) search index using an entity content type, but I don't need to index all the fields. Is there a way to add a relationship to the referenced entities in the view? All I see are items with the 'Content datasource' category.

Perhaps I am missing something when building the search index?

Thank you!